# rails prawn undefined method rowspan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I get the following error for the code below: `undefined method 'rowspan=' for #<Prawn::Table::Cell::Text:0x9477540>`

```
table [
    [{content: "<b>control</b>", rowspan: 2}, 
     {content: "time", colspan: 2}, 
     "order", 
     {content: "count", colspan: 6}]
  ], cell_style: {size: 10, inline_format: true}
```

I followed the prawn manual, and can not see what I did wrong. I am using prawn 0.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Prawn google group, colspan and rowspan were not introduced until a later release.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/prawn-ruby/rowspan/prawn-ruby/G-QHFUZheMI/3a4pNnLur0EJ

Updating to the lastest master gem from github worked for me:

> git clone https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git

Create a directory to test the manual example.
Run bundle init to create a Gemfile in that directory and add this line

```
gem 'prawn', :path=>'/path/to/your/local/prawn/git/clone/dir'
```

Create the span_example.rb file from the manual, and set it up to use bundler Gemfile like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require

pdf = Prawn::Document.generate('span_example.pdf') do

  table([
      ["A", {content: "2x1", colspan: 2}, "B"],
      [{content: "1x2", rowspan: 2}, "C", "D", "E"],
      [{content: "2x2", colspan: 2, :rowspan => 2}, "F"],
      ["G", "H"]
  ])

end
```

Then run

```
bundle install
ruby span_example.rb
open span_example.pdf
```

Viola!